# Creating a custom NAS compatible with the Mac Time machine and for media streaming

Tags: nas, time-machine

I am planning to assemble a custom NAS machine using an Intel Atom processor. I need the NAS for the following purposes:

- It should be accessible from my Windows PC so that I can dump data on the NAS (installations, media etc)
- It should be accessible from my Macbook for the above use.
- I should be able to use it with the Mac time machine software for backup.
- The media should be available to my PS3 for streaming.
- I should be able to access it from my iphone. (not very important)

All the above features should be available over wireless.

**The time machine feature is very important.**

Is this possible? Can someone provide resources on how I can assemble such a machine and setup the required software on it?

Much appreciated.

Comment: I am in precisely the same situation, been digging around for info for weeks!

Answer (score 1):

In terms of software, any reasonably modern linux distro will do well for this purpose.

- The 'samba' package will do standard Windows file sharing without issue
- The 'netatalk' package (and afpd server) will do Apple file sharing, including full Time Machine support
- Mediatomb, if I recall correctly, will do UPnP streaming to PS3 and other compatible devices

What are you looking to access from the iphone?

An Atom-based system will work fairly well, but you'll have to do a bunch of research to find exactly the hardware you want.

As a start, I've found a couple of decent Mini-ITX cases that will work for NAS purposes:

- The Fractal Design Array holds up to 6x3.5" disks; review: http://www.silentpcreview.com/fractal-array
- The Chenbro ES34169 has 4 hot-swap SATA bays: http://usa.chenbro.com/corporatesite/products_detail.php?sku=167

I can't provide much advice for the rest of the hardware. It really depends how many disks you want, how much redundancy you need, etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot David. I am really not looking for the hardware information. I am more interested in the software to enable the services I mentioned. The iPhone data access is really not important. I just need to access pictures and video.